# CSS таблица выходит за область

Tags: html, css

Есть обычная таблица html, но при масштабировании ее часть выходит за пределы видимости. Как сделать так чтобы таблица не выходила за пределы, а просто сужалась?

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: нем нет ничего кроме <table></table>, стилей вообще нет

Comment: Слышал о том, что `<table>` лучше не использовать.

Comment: width:100%;max-width:100%;

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, почему же нет?)

Comment: таблица нужна для табличных данных, а лучше не использовать для общей сетки

Comment: @entithat, честно - не помню, но лично видел, что она много где работает коряво при изменение размера.

Comment: ну дык верстать надо, чтобы не коряво было, обертывать контейнером для скролла и пр

Comment: Таблицу в блок вставьте <div><table></table></div>
ну и ширину таблицы выставьте не в пикселях а в %. К примеру 100%

Comment: Так автор вроде же и не говорил что собирается использовать таблицу для сетки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таблица может поместиться в экран, то достаточно ограничить ее добавлением ширины 100%. Если таблицу невозможно поместить по ширине, то один из самых быстрых и простых вариантов - это обернуть её дивом, который добавит горизонтальный скролл внутри себя, не выходя за пределы существующей сетки:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<br>...
<br>какой-то конетнт
<br>...
<br>
<br>


<div class=wrap>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>...
<br>какой-то конетнт
<br>...
```